# Kafka - How to check if the consumer is alive, if not how to bring back the consumer to a running state?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm currently working on a kafka java project. I'm new to it and I'm finding it difficult to understand few basic concepts associated with Kafka Producer/Consumer design.

1. Say, I have a topic with single partition and I have a producer writing to it and a consumer consuming from the topic. If I deploy multiple instances of the same application, each instance will be running a consumer of it's own. In this case, since all the consumers belong to the same groupId, will the messages be equally distributed among the consumers running on multiple instances?
2. How can I check if a consumer is alive in a periodic fashion from the application?.
3. If one/all consumers goes down how do I restart/bring it back to running state?
4. What's the best way to implement a long-running consumer in java?.

Kindly provide clarifications for the above queries.
Please do correct me, if any/all of my assumptions/understanding is wrong.
I know that I have not shared any code samples, since these are conceptual questions. I can share the code snippets, if required.

Answer (score 0):

1. You said topic with single partition means it doesn't way to distribute messages to multiple partition. You will loose one of the big advantage of Kafka. You mush increase partition more than one. 
   If you deploy multiple instance of the same application it doesn't help to distribute because message are publishing into one partition as you mentioned and only one instance will only be assigned to that partition other instances will just be idle.
2. You can use AdminClient Kafka API to check if any lagging on your consumer

   ```
   Properties props = new Properties();
   props.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9091");
   KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
   AdminClient client = org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClient.create(props);
   ListConsumerGroupOffsetsResult offsets = client.listConsumerGroupOffsets("consumerId");
   Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> tt = offsets.partitionsToOffsetAndMetadata().get();
   ListConsumerGroupOffsetsResult offsets = client.listConsumerGroupOffsets(consumerId);
   Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> tt = offsets.partitionsToOffsetAndMetadata().get();
   for (Entry<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> entry : tt.entrySet()) {TopicPartition tp = entry.getKey();
     OffsetAndMetadata op = entry.getValue();
     Collections.singletonList(tp);
     consumer.assign(Collections.singletonList(tp));
     consumer.seekToEnd(Collections.singletonList(tp));
     System.out.println(consumerId + "," + tp.partition() + "," + consumer.position(tp) + ","
                               + op.offset() + "," + (consumer.position(tp) - op.offset()));
   }
   ```
3. You have not stated where you deployed , t but if you deployed using marathon in mesos, It will get restart automatically. You can restart manually and if you use same group id as previous your application will start consuming where it left.

Answer (score -1):

1. Kafka will only allow one consumer per partition and consumer group. So multiple consumers will wait until the main consumer goes down, then will jump in at that point, but only one consumer at a time will ever be consuming for a given partition / consumer group.
2. You can check that the consumer groups offset is keeping up with the max offset to see if there is lag. Kafka does a pretty good job of cycling through multiple consumers if one starts having issues
3. Restart the app and it will pick up from where it left off, just don’t restart the messages from the beginning. Kafka handles that for you.
4. We use spring boot with spring Kafka. There’s no ‘best’ way, but we find it easy to set up and maintain with spring.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. How do you check if a consumer is alive at any point of time?. How to bring the consumer back live after it's down?

Comment: What do you mean ‘alive’?